# How do I typeset this piecewise function?

Tags: equations, formatting, brackets

[image]

What is the LaTeX code for this? There is a solution about how to code the function part, but I could not find out how to make all that equal to f(x). Please ignore the semicolons in the piecewise function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be looking for the `cases` environment of the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'cases' env. and '\text' macro
\begin{document}
\[
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
4x   & x\le0 \text{ ise}\\
3x^2 & x>0   \text{ ise}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can built also an array like the example shown below to reproduce the correct command `\cases` in these circumstances. The `[.5em]` it is the vertical spacing between the two equations that you can increase or decrease.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
  
\begin{document}
\[f(x)=\Bigl\{\begin{array}{ll}
    4x & x\leq 0\,  \text{ ise } \\
    3x^2 & x>0\, \text{ ise } 
\end{array}
\]

\[f(x)=\Biggl\{\begin{array}{ll}
    4x & x\leq 0\,  \text{ ise } \\[.5em]
    3x^2 & x>0\, \text{ ise } 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]